# How to pass Multivalued parameters through URL in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, urlaccess

I have main matrix report and I want to navigate my sub report from main report by 
Jump To URL:(Using below JavaScript function) method.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://localhost/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fKonsolidata_Data_Exporting_Project%2fEXPORT_REPORT_TEST&rs:Command=Render&RP_cntry="+Fields!STD_CTRY_NM.Value+"&RP_cll_typ_l1="+Join(Parameters!RP_cll_typ_l1.Value,",")+"'))"
```

It is ok for the Single valued but giving exception for the multivalued

Like

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) 
Cannot read the next data row for the data set DS_GRID_DATA. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3,4' to data type int.
```

Basically I have defined Parameters!RP_cll_typ_l1 as multivalued into my subreport as per ssrs multivalued parameter passing method.
The value is going on sub report as '1,2,3,4' (not understandable by data set)
It should be like as '1’,’2’,’3’,’4' or 1,2,3,4 
How can I resolve this please help if any have solution?

Thanks

Kali Charan Tripathi(India)

tripathi_soft@yahoo.co.in

kalicharan.tripathi@in.schneider-electric.com

Answer (score 5):

To use multvalue parameters via URLAccess in SSRS, you have to repeat the parameter names for each value

So instead of

```
...&RP_cll_typ_l1=1,2,3,4&...
```

you would have

```
...&RP_cll_typ_l1=1&RP_cll_typ_l1=2&RP_cll_typ_l1=3&RP_cll_typ_l1=4&...
```